# How to match the nondirectory part of a filename with a regular expression?

Tags: regular-expressions, git, filenames

Whats the correct way to match a filename from a full path using `string-match-p`.

Say I want to check if the file is a git commit message `COMMIT_EDITMSG` or `svn-commit.tmp` or `svn-commit.3.tmp` to pass to 3rd party code that only takes regular expressions (something like `auto-mode-alist`).

eg: `(string-match my-clever-regex "/path/to/svn-commit.3.tmp")`

Using the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` as an example:

- `"COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'"` also matches `PREFIX_COMMIT_EDITMSG`.
- `"/COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'"` fails to match `COMMIT_EDITMSG` or `\COMMIT_EDITMSG`.

How can I match a filename which may or may not contain a path?

Comment: Match how/where? Isearch? `grep`, `re-search-forward`? Emacs regexp or regexp for `find` or something else? Define *"correct"*. Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: Updated to include details.

Comment: Emacs lisp provides [specific functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Names.html#File-Names) to extract parts of filenames: no regex needed.

Comment: Agree this makes sense in isolation, the reason I'm asking is because a package I'm developing provides a user setting which matches a regex against a buffer paths, so inserting arbitrary code isn't as clean an option, since I cant guess which part of the path the user will want to check.

Comment: If you're matching `buffer-file-name`, that *will* have a directory component to it, in which case `"/COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'"` may be all you need for a regexp.

Comment: @phils couldn't this be a "\" on WIN32? also, why end with `\'` instead of `$` ?

Comment: I don't know whether it could be `\ ` on WIN32 because I've no idea where this value is coming from; but if it's coming from Emacs then you may find that it's `/` even on WIN32.  I suggest either testing this yourself, or else giving details so that someone else would be able to do so.

Comment: `\'` because that's the correct way to say "end of text". Whilst not recommended, newlines *are* valid in filenames on most systems, so `$` is potentially insufficient.  For more examples see virtually every entry in `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: [This](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?289178-A-file-called-C-nppdf32Log-debuglog-txt-in-my-root-directory) happens when you don't listen to @Stefan 's advice!

Comment: @Rusi I'm just matching a path, not creating one.

Comment: FWIW, as far as I can tell, all entries in `auto-mode-alist` just use `/` for that purpose.  Emacs accepts `\` as directory separator in Windows, but it tends to convert them to `/` on many occasions.

Comment: BTW, @Rusi: Terrible things happen when you don't follow my advice!  You've all been warned!

Comment: @Stefan: StackExchange mangled your syntax -- you might want to recreate that comment.  For `\ ` you can put a space between the backslash and the closing backtick, to prevent the former from just escaping the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression matches both `COMMIT_EDITMSG` and `/path/to/COMMIT_EDITMSG`.

```el
(string-match-p "\\`\\(?:.*[\\/]\\)?COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'" "/path/to/COMMIT_EDITMSG")
```

---

If the filename is from `buffer-file-name` there is no need to check for `\` separators as Emacs converts them to `/`, there is also no need to account for no need to account for only the filename case as the filename will either be the full path or `./`.

Since this isn't part of the original question, adding this as a second example.

```el
(string-match-p "/COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'" "/path/to/COMMIT_EDITMSG")
```

---

Thanks to suggestions from @phils which helped improve this answer.

Comment: `\\(\\|foo\\)` is a bit simpler as `\\(foo\\)?`.

Comment: Where are you receiving paths with backslash separators from?  AFAIK it's uncommon to have to deal with DOS separators explicitly -- see `(elisp)File Names`

Comment: Assuming you don't need to capture that sub-group, I'd suggest `"\\(?:\\\`\\|[\\/]\\)COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'"` (n.b. newlines are valid in filenames).  And if you don't need to support backslashes then just `/` instead of `[\\/]` of course.  And maybe go with `string-match-p` if you aren't capturing anything.

Comment: The filenames are from `buffer-file-name`, which might be called on a windows system.

Comment: In which case I believe you can forget about `\ ` as Emacs stores file names using `/` internally so that elisp programs work consistently across systems.  The aforementioned note in `(elisp)File Names` will certainly be applicable to `buffer-file-name`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do

```
(equal "COMMIT_EDITMSG"
       (file-name-nondirectory <file>))
```

Comment: This question asked about using regular expressions which is significant, I've updated my question to explain why I can't use some elisp to check the string.